# How to run Docker container with website and php?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a landing page and one PHP file to send emails (feedback form). I want to test this form using Docker.

I've written this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD [ "php", "/mail/contact_me.php"]
```

But it doesn't work for me.

I have the directory `mail` with the PHP file in the root of the project, but I'm still unsure if the Dockerfile is correct:

- Is it enough to inherit `FROM php:7.4-cli` or do I have to add nginx server to run the image?
- What does the line `COPY . /usr/src/app` exactly do? Is this correct?

Comment: You will need an Nginx webserver and php containers.

Comment: could you, please, as answer write how Dockerfile should looks like? thanks @invalidbot

Comment: I've edited your question for a better understanding and a better readabilty. Therefore I restructured your text to focus more on your questions (each of your question is now a bullet point at the end and not inside the code snippet). It would be also nice if you can include error messages you have received. Please read also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and potentially edit your question with suggestions from there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `Dockerfile` is used when you want to create a custom image.

`FROM php:7.4-cli` specifies the **base image** you want to customize.
`COPY . /usr/src/app` copie the **host** current directory `.` into the **container** `/usr/src/app`.
`CMD [ "php", "/mail/contact_me.php"]` specifies what command to run within the container.

In your case, I don't think a custom image is required.

As you need a webserver with PHP, you can use the `php:7.4.3-apache` image which comes with `PHP7` and `Apache` webserver pre-installed. All you need to do is copy your app to your container, or use a volume. A volume is great because it actually mounts your host directory into your container, allowing you to edit your app from the host and see changes in real-time.

You can use a `docker-compose.yml` file for that.

```
version: "2"
services:
  webserver:
    image: php:7.4.3-apache
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
```

Assuming your application is located in an `app` folder on your host machine, this folder will get mounted at `/var/html/html` on your container. Here the `8181:80` will redirect the `8181` port on your host machine to the `80` port of your container, which is the http port.

Use this command to start your container:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Your should see your landing page at `http://localhost:8181`

Comment: so "./app:" is my folder of project? for example my project is "myproject" folder with all code.
So i have to write "./myproject:/var/www/html"?

Comment: I`ve got on the localhost:8181:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8181

Comment: [Here](http://snippi.com/s/jqan7po) is how your files should be organized according to the code I posted. Then you can access your app at localhost:8181/index.php

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["php", "/usr/src/app/mail/contact_me.php"]
```

Here's a breakdown of the changes made:

Added `WORKDIR` instruction to set the working directory to `/usr/src/app`. This will be the base directory for subsequent instructions.

Modified the `CMD` instruction to provide the correct path to the PHP script. Assuming the `contact_me.php` file is located in the mail directory inside the image, we specify the full path as `/usr/src/app/mail/contact_me.php`.

Please note that you should ensure the directory structure and file locations match your project setup.

Answer (score -2):

Read there about Dockerfile (official documentation): [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

And
may be you need another Docker image: [Docker HUB ~> bitnami/php-fpme](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/php-fpm)